# Why use .execute in Gmail API discovery in python

Tags: python, gmail-api

I have a query in regards to accessing gmail api using python. Below, I have the discovery build `service`, then using [gmail api documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest), we can access different REST resources, for example, accessing labels and to list all the labels like below. But in the script, there is `.execute()`after `list`, I'm wondering which documentation tells me that I need to include `.execute()` to get this working?

```
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='youremail').execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the request `service.users().labels().list(userId='youremail')` is just a construct the request, but is not getting executed or processed yet. You need to use the method `execute()` to complete this process. Remember that the `execute()` method will execute the given operation (query or command).

You can see it being used in the [Google Documentation samples](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python). Like this one:

[image: email List sample]

You can also see the same behavior in the official Workspace Github repositories samples [here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/tree/main/gmail/snippet)

E.g.
The one for sending emails:

[image: sample send email]

You can also review for refences this blog from [thepythoncode.com](https://www.thepythoncode.com/code/use-gmail-api-in-python) or [betterprogramming.pub](https://betterprogramming.pub/a-beginners-guide-to-the-google-gmail-api-and-its-documentation-c73495deff08).

Also, I access to the discovery.py library

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

And I found this documentation:

```
 Returns:
          A request object that you can call 'execute()' on to request the next
          page. Returns None if there are no more items in the collection.
```